# What causes jQuery objects to be different?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Why doesn't the first attempt to close the dialog work?  Or maybe a better question is why is jQuery object `$("#dialog")` different than `$(this).parent('div.dialog')`?

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});

$("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen:false}).find('li').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('div.dialog').dialog('close');
    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
});

    <div id="dialog">
        <ul>
            <li>111</li>
            <li>222</li>
            <li>333</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: "why is jQuery object $("#dialog") different than $(this).parent('div.dialog')?" Impossible to say without seeing the HTML. Does `#dialog` have a class named `dialog`? Ex. `<div id="dialog" class="dialog"></div>`

Comment: In case 1, you are selecting by ID. In case 2, you are selecting by class. They may not be returning the same element, depending on your DOM

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the HTML.

Comment: @user1032531 there is no div with dialog class in your html. it returns empty

Comment: @MehulMohan  The jQueryUI dialog plugin will add it.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  I need `parents()`

Comment: @Tankor: while I disagree my comment was personal, it is obsolete, so deleted regardless.

Comment: @DavidThomas  I incorrectly got on the wrong track, and incorrectly "knew" that `parent()` goes all the way up the DOM until finding a match, so what I was seeing obviously made no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).parent('div.dialog')` will only look up one level to see if the parent matches that selector. It will not traverse any further. The result is an empty set, and as a result using `.dialog()` has no effect.

What would work here would be [`closest` <sup>jQuery API</sup>](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$(this).closest('div.dialog')
```

This would be the same as `$("#dialog")` in your example.

Comment: Thanks Travis.  I think `parents()` will also work, no?

Comment: `parents` will also work, but it will return a set, which could then match incorrectly if there were more than one matches. It is also not necessary to get all matches in this case, so using only the first one seemed to make more sense.

Comment: Yes, I agree `closest()` is best.  Thanks.  Can wait to select this answer and get this behind me!  I incorrectly assumed `parent()` went all the way up, and didn't understand what I was witnessing.